# how to clear the specified child of canvas in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas

Please Help me, How to clear the specified child of canvas in windows phone 7

Thanks .

Comment: show us codes please .

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
canvas.Children.Remove(uiElement);
```

where uiElement is the child you want to remove.

or

```
canvas.Children.RemoveAt(1);
```

where 1 is the index of this element in child collection

Comment: Thank You for reply.. i have a multiple Images in background Canvas and also another child canvas to background canvas now i want to remove only those images without removing of child canvas. how can i do?

Comment: Kindly , can you show me you lines for this part to understand